# Change the way how actions for FileManager are displayed

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I installed `FileManager-Actions` to have customized actions for context menu. The application works as expected, however, I'd like to know whether it is possible to have an item displayed directly. By default it is nested in menu as you can see in the following picture. I cannot find an appropriate option in the application.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had this problem as well, gotta love 18.04 regressions. Your fix is to uncheck "Create a root 'FileManager-Actions' menu" in Runtime preferences.